# MaterialButton size difference to Button

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I' am setting up a new application and came across the fact that the materialButton's height does't match the size which i set.
So i tried on the regular Button and as you guys can see in the screenshot below.
The buttons have different height although they getting the same height as you can see in my code.

How can i get normal height with MaterialButton?

Thank you.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
MaterialButton materialButton;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setId(getGeneratedId());

    setContentView(linearLayout);

    int buttonWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.buttonWidth);
    int buttonHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.buttonHeight);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(buttonWidth, buttonHeight);

    materialButton = new MaterialButton(this);
    materialButton.setId(getGeneratedId());
    materialButton.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    materialButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    materialButton.setText("MatrialB");
    materialButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);


    button = new Button(this);
    button.setId(getGeneratedId());
    button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    button.setText("Button");
    button.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    linearLayout.addView(materialButton);
    linearLayout.addView(button);
    
}

Integer getGeneratedId() {
    return ViewCompat.generateViewId();
}
```

}

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: They are the same height. Use Layout Inspector in Android Studio to confirm that. You can also use Layout Inspector to try to determine why the *rendering* differs. It might be the background shape used by `MaterialButton`, or `MaterialButton` might define a default top/bottom margin.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare that i can confirm. The difference between all the properties are the padding. The normal button hast mPaddingTop 27, mPaddingBottom 27 and mUserPaddingBottom 27. The material Buttons has the same values but these ones additionally mUserPaddingEnd 44, mUserPaddingLeft 44, mUserPaddingRight 44 & mUserPaddingStart 44. I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: Add some padding to your `Button`, I guess.

Comment: It's just moving the button down away from the textfield inside.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you have another suggestion? I'm still facing the issue..

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know what "moving the button down away from the textfield inside" means.

Answer (score 59):

I believe the space on top and bottom of the MaterialButton is coming from `android:insetTop`/`android:insetBottom` which is `6dp` for me with material components 1.0.0. I am not sure, how to set these programmatically, but it can be done easily in xml:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:insetBottom="0dp"
      android:insetTop="0dp"/>
```

Comment: Thank you, i will check that.

Comment: Awesome answer! In addition use "app:backgroundTint" to change button's background color and use "app:cornerRadius" to change button's radius.

Answer (score 29):

The `MaterialButton` has a default style with `insetBottom` and `insetTop` with a value of `6dp`.

You can check the difference without/with the vertical insets:

[image]

You can change the default with:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"
```

or programmatically (it requires at least `1.3.0-alpha03`) with:

```
    button.insetTop = 0
    button.insetBottom = 0
```